# Logic App - Create CSV table from JSON output

Tags: csv, azure-logic-apps, azure-runbook

I've created a Runbook which starts or shutsdown VMs and then spits the result in a JSON output. I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to take that output and use it in a 'Create CSV Table' within my Logic App.

Output (which is exactly how it comes into the Logic App):

```
[
    {
        'VM':  'MyVM2',
        'Success':  true,
        'PSComputerName':  'localhost',
        'PSShowComputerName':  true,
        'PSSourceJobInstanceId':  '286eeccb-c7f6-4afd-a734-7f4e837ffdac'
    },
    {
        'VM':  'MyVM1',
        'Success':  true,
        'PSComputerName':  'localhost',
        'PSShowComputerName':  true,
        'PSSourceJobInstanceId':  '286eeccb-c7f6-4afd-a734-7f4e837ffdac'
    }
]
```

My Logic App flow:
[image]

However I am prompted with the following error when it runs because the ‘Create CSV Table’ doesn’t like the input:
[image]

I’m sure it’s just some sort of formatting that needs to be changed, but I am unsure how to do it. I'm new to learning code, and as far as I can tell the output is an Array of Objects, but the error is asking for an Array. Perhaps some sort of limitation?

I'm aware of using Pars JSON, **however** the results will not always be the same. Sometimes I will have 2 results in the output, or sometimes I will have 20 results. Therefore if I define the schema in Parse JSON for only 2 results, it will omit the rest because they are not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies to those who have already answered the question, but during that time I was able to create a table a different way, and have since excessively progressed with my logic app.

```
Create_CSV_table": {
            "inputs": {
                "format": "CSV",
                "from": "@json(outputs('Compose'))"
            },
```

...and thus the output was like:

[image: logic app]

I hope that your answers will help others (or myself later on) for anyone viewing this page.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm aware of using Pars JSON, however the results will not always be the same. Sometimes I will have 2 results in the output, or sometimes I will have 20 results. Therefore if I define the schema in Parse JSON for only 2 results, it will omit the rest because they are not defined.

You also could use the Pars JSON, if the peperties of the each record are fixed. Please have a try to use the following Schema. I test it on my side, it works correctly.

```
{
    "items": {
        "properties": {
            "PSComputerName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "PSShowComputerName": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "PSSourceJobInstanceId": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "Success": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "VM": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "VM",
            "Success",
            "PSComputerName",
            "PSShowComputerName",
            "PSSourceJobInstanceId"
        ],
        "type": "object"
    },
    "type": "array"
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

please follow below steps :

1) First you need to remove "Compose" action

2) In "Create CSV Table" action From textbox pass content of "Get Job output" 
   action connector which you pass in "Compose" Action

Then its working

Problem : when you pass "Get Job output" action content into "Compose" action its convert content datatype array to string . "Create CSV Table" only array datatype content